# How to scale symbols (circles) on plot of point realization

Tags: spatstat

I am learning to make some plots in spatstat. I created a poisson point process of just one kind and attached some marks to it - a numerical value. Now when I plot, the plot has by default - circles. These circles are of relative proportion , But these circles are too big on my network. I want to ask if there is some scaling factor to control size of these circles drawn at point realizations.

So, I extracted points from point pattern process and using their x,y I was able to control this with the cex argument in plot function. But this does not control the size in the legend. So I tried to define a basic r legend() function to draw it on the plot. This is lot of additional work and is specific to each case.

So I am wondering if there is some scaling argument for plotting these realizations and their legends from within the spatstat functions.

Could someone guide me please.

Comment: I tried a few things like maxsize, i get this advise, but I do not understand how to use diameter. _Interpretation of arguments maxsize and markscale has changed (in spatstat version 1.37-0 and later). Size of a circle is now measured by its diameter._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use the argument `markscale` to set the scaling of the marks (incl.
in the legend). The built-in dataset `spruces` has both coordinates and
marks in meters, so to represent the tree sizes on a true scale you set
`markscale = 1`. This means that the **diameter** (and not the radius as
previously) of the circle representing the tree is equal to the mark
value measured in the coordinate units of the window. So this would be a
"true" map of the forrest:

```r
library(spatstat)
plot(spruces, markscale = 1)
#> Warning: Interpretation of arguments maxsize and markscale has changed (in
#> spatstat version 1.37-0 and later). Size of a circle is now measured by its
#> diameter.
```

[image]

If the mark values had been in decimetre you would have to do

```r
plot(spruces, markscale = 10)
```

[image]